# Quick question: Best way to design PDF templates with Angular and .NET 6, focusing on table-heavy layouts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, pdfmake

What is the best solution for designing PDF templates with Angular and .NET 6? The main requirement is to be able to design templates that primarily consist of tables

In my quest to create efficient PDF templates with Angular and .NET 6, I decided to give pdfmake a shot. Unfortunately, the journey was met with hurdles as the solution didn't meet my expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience it is always to generate the pdf from a server side library e.g .NET. Then handle it on your frontend as a blob. Some examples of libraries are QuestPDF, IronPdf and so on

Comment: Is leveraging IronPDF server-side in an Angular application the optimal solution for generating a PDF from the Angular screen? Currently, we render the screen in Angular, send the HTML (via document.documentElement.innerHTML) to our WebAPI, which efficiently converts it to a PDF and returns a URI. ?

Comment: ideally, you would want to send the data you want to add to the table to the api . On the API , using IronPDF for instance, create the table of however you want the structure to be on the pdf and send it as a stream. On the UI you will handle the stream as a blob where you save it on the browser